# How to add/remove class in ngFor span in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Managed to add `class` on `ngFor` span when I click it however I'm trying to remove the current class if I click another span.

Say I have these spans coming from `ngFor`, when I click S it will add a class `active-span` and if I click M it will add a class `active-span` but remove the class from S.

```
<span class="jersey-size" [ngClass]="{'active-span': size.active}" (click)="getSizeData(size)">{{  size.size }}</span>
```

click function using `Renderer`

```
select(event:any){
  event.preventDefault()
  this.render.setElementClass(event.target, "active-span", true || false);
}
```

or using `ngClass` but this is only toggles the class.

```
select(size){
 size.active = !size.active;
}
<span class="jersey-size" [ngClass]="{'active-span': size.active}" (click)="getSizeData(size)">{{  size.size }}</span>
```

My problem is how can I remove the class from the previous span selected when I select/click a new span?

Comment: how many spans types (names) do you have ? two ?

Comment: shouldn't matter right because its being rendered dynamically using `ngFor` so it could be 2 or 5. But in my count there will be 4 sizes (S, M, L, XL).

Comment: How do you store your choice in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store the size choice (or index)(and you will need it to store in db no?) then use it like:

```
[ngClass]="{'active-span': size.size === selectedSize}"
```

your controller could be something like (or use your proper object if you already have one to store it):

```
selectedSize: string;
select(size){
 this.selectedSize = size.size;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorted now :) I was kind of doing similar earlier but I put falsey in `!size.size`.